# Compute $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin 2x}{9+x^{2}} \, dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin 2x}{9+x^{2}} \, dx$$

Some rearranging eventually gives
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin 2x}{9+x^{2}} \, dx = \frac{-i}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{xe^{2ix}}{9+x^{2}}$$
Consider $f(z) = \frac{ze^{2iz}}{9+z^{2}}$ and the contour $\gamma$ of the semicircle laying in the upper half of the plane:
[image: contour]

Let $\gamma_{R}$ denote the circular part with radius $R$ and $\gamma_{L}$ denote the part lying on the real axis with length $2R$.

Computing the residue at the only pole, $z = 3i$, we have that
$$\oint_{\gamma}f(z) \, dz = \frac{i\pi}{e^{6}} $$
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
\oint_{\gamma}f(z) \, dz &= \oint_{\gamma_{R}}f(z) \, dz + \oint_{\gamma_{L}} f(z) \, dz \\
&= \oint_{\gamma_{R}} f(z) \, dz + \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{xe^{2ix}}{9+x^{2}} \, dx
\end{align*}
We may evaluate the first integral in the usual way by parameterizing the contour and taking $z = Re^{i\theta}$.
\begin{align*}
\oint_{\gamma_{R}} f(z) \, dz = \int_{0}^{\pi} \, \frac{R^{2}e^{2i\theta}e^{2i\cos\theta}e^{-2R\sin\theta}}{(9+R^{2}e^{2i\theta})} d\theta
\end{align*}

I'm aiming to show that this integral goes to $0$ as $R$ goes to infinity. This gives the desired result as the factor of $\frac{-i}{2}$ is all that is missing according to WolframAlpha. I'm not sure how to finish it though.

Comment: Factor $R^2$ from the denominator to cancel the one in the numerator and then take the limit as R approaches infinity which will show it goes to zero

Comment: Shouldn't that be $9+R^2e^{2i\theta}$ in the denominator of the last integral?

Comment: You're right. edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before addressing the question regarding the limit of the integral over $\gamma_R$, it is important to first understand that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(2x)}{9+x^2}\,dx=\frac12\text{Im}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{xe^{i2x}}{9+x^2}\,dx\right)$$

Next, using the residue theorem we find that

$$\oint_\gamma \frac{ze^{i2z}}{9+z^2}\,dz=2\pi i \frac{3i(e^{-6})}{6i}=\pi ie^{-6}$$

---

Now, to address the question regarding the limit of the integral over $\gamma_R$, we first note that

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^\pi \frac{Re^{i\phi }e^{i2Re^{i\phi}}}{9+R^2e^{i2\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\right|&\le \int_0^\pi \frac{R^2e^{-2R\sin(\phi)}}{|9+R^2e^{i2\phi}|}\\\\
&\le \frac{2R^2}{|R^2-9|}\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-2R\sin(\phi)}\,d\phi\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Next, we use the fact that $\sin(\phi)\ge 2\phi/\pi$ for $\phi \in[0,\pi/2]$.  Hence, we can write

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-2R\sin(\phi)}\,d\phi\le \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-4R\phi/\pi}\,d\phi=\frac{1-e^{-2R}}{4R/\pi}\tag 2$$

Using $(2)$ in $(1)$ we find that

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^\pi \frac{Re^{i\phi }e^{i2Re^{i\phi}}}{9+R^2e^{i2\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\right|\le \frac{2R^2}{|R^2-9|}\frac{1-e^{-2R}}{4R/\pi}\to 0\,\,\text{as}\,\,R\to \infty
\end{align}$$

---

Comment: Lol, don't doubt yourself so much XD

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: :P You deleted your own answer, though I thought it was good.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt There was a flaw in the first post that I needed to edit.  But thank you for your comment!

Comment: Safe and Sound. (+1)

Comment: @HazemOrabi Hazem, thank you!  Much appreciative.

Comment: Looks great thanks. Between (1) and (2) that should be "for $\phi \in [0, \pi/2]$".

Comment: @JPelter You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I've edited the typo.

Answer (score 3):

I'll use the duality of the convolution theorem to find the spectrum $\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{x}{9 + x^2}\right)$ as the convolution of the two spectra $\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{9 + x^2}\right)$ and $\mathcal{F}\left(x\right)$. The spectrum of the first (Cauchy) function is well-known, being a symmetric mono-exponential, and the second spectrum is $\left(-i \sqrt{2\pi} δ'(ω)\right)$, being the differential operator in the Fourier domain times $i$.

$$\begin{align} I &= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin 2x}{9+x^{2}} \, dx  \\ &=\frac{1}{2}\Im\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{x}{9 + x^2}\right)_{\omega = 2}\right)  \\ &=\frac{1}{2}\Im\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{9 + x^2}\right) \otimes \sqrt{2\pi}\mathcal{F}\left(x\right)}{2\pi}\right)_{\omega = 2}  \\ &=\frac{1}{2}\Im\left(\frac 1 3 \sqrt{\frac\pi 2} e^{(-3|ω|)} \otimes -i \sqrt{2\pi} δ'(ω)\right)_{\omega = 2} \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\Im\left(i\left[\frac 1 3  e^{(-3|ω|)}\right]' \right)_{\omega = 2}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\left[\frac 1 3  e^{(-3|ω|)}\right]'_{\omega = 2}  \\  &=\frac{\pi}{2 e^{6}} \\ &\approx 0.003893... \end{align}$$

Comment: I don't know anything about the machinery you're using, but there [must](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B(x+Sin%5B2+x%5D)%2F(9+%2B+x%5E2),+%7Bx,+0,+%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) be an error somewhere. Thank you though.

Comment: @JPelter : thanks, I have corrected my solution.

Comment: It is nice applications for Fourier transform I need to learn. But can you please write more details for education purposes? Finally I got it.

Answer (score 2):

We may also use the Laplace transform to evaluate the integral. Using [this useful identity of the Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) we have $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin\left(2x\right)}{x^{2}+9}dx\stackrel{2x\rightarrow x}{=}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin\left(x\right)}{x^{2}+36}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(6x\right)}{x^{2}+1}dx.$$ Let us consider $$I\left(a\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(ax\right)}{x^{2}+1}dx,\,a>0.$$ Then if we apply again the Laplace transform we have $$\mathfrak{L}\left(I\left(a\right)\right)\left(s\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(ax\right)}{x^{2}+1}e^{-as}dadx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{s}{\left(x^{2}+s^{2}\right)\left(1+x^{2}\right)}dx$$ hence using partial fractions $$\mathfrak{L}\left(I\left(a\right)\right)\left(s\right)=\frac{\pi}{2\left(s+1\right)}$$ so inverting $$I\left(a\right)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2e^{a}}}.$$ Taking $a=6$ we have the result.

Answer (score 0):

Also can be fairly nice to utilize Laplace transform this way.
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin 2x}{9+x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x&=\int_0^{\infty}\mathcal{L}\left[\sin\left(2t\right)\right](x)\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{t}{t^{2}+9}\right](x)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2\cos(3x)}{x^{2}+4}\mathrm{d}x\\
&\overset{*}=\frac{\pi}{2e^6}.
\end{align}

where (*) can be evaluated as by Marco Cantarini or other different approaches like here [Evaluating $\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}dx$ without complex analysis or Fourier Transform?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220248).