# Integration closed contours

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin(x)}{x^2 +4} dx$$
I do not understand how to evaluate integrals  by using a closed contour and passing to a limit, can someone show me using this example

Comment: I suggest you look at the old questions. Similar questions have been posted over and over again.

Comment: It took me less than a minute to find http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172184/compute-int-0-infty-fracx-sin-2x9x2-dx

Comment: i still don't understand

Comment: What exactly you don't understand ? Write what you have tried so far.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai good catch! why not officially making this a duplicate?

Comment: @tired If so all integral is duplicate! Because it's integral!

Comment: @Zaid Alyafeai It's exactly, that I said! We calculate an integrals by the same approaches. Let be close all topics with integrals!

Comment: @Zaid Alyafeai In this forum often enough close an interesting topics with nice wards similar to your. Maybe in our case you are right, but see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190801 This topic will be close!  I don't agree with this thing.